# Действие при закрытие программы Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возможно ли сделать, чтобы при закрытии программы python, например, создавался и открывался файл, в общем вот нажал пользователь на крестик, программа вместо того чтобы сразу закрыться отрабатывает какой-либо код?

Comment: что такое "программа python"?

Comment: На какой именно крестик нажимает пользователь? Крестик окна консоли? Крестик окна интерфейса, созданного самим питоном?

Comment: `import signal` и дальше по документации

Answer (score 0):

если речь про окно TKinter, то вот код:

```
window = Tk()
def quit():
    действие_при_закрытии
window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", quit)
```